# How to breakdown an array multidimension in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem in detailing array numbers as below

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 1000
      'kali' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 2000
      'kali' => string '5' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 5000
      'kali' => string '1' (length=1)
```

What should i do if the end result is as follows

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 1000
      'kali' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 1000
      'kali' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 2000
      'kali' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 2000
      'kali' => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 2000
      'kali' => string '5' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 2000
      'kali' => string '6' (length=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 2000
      'kali' => string '7' (length=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'um' => float 5000
      'kali' => string '8' (length=1)
```

String `['kali']` loop as much as the previous array

for example: 
`['kali'] = 2` looping 2 times
`['kali'] = 5` looping 5 times
etc..

Please enlighten this case

Comment: Why is there only four um => 2000 in your output. Shouldn't it be 5?

Comment: Oh yeah.. its should be 5, tks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `foreach` loop may do it as:

```
$cnt = 1;
foreach($arr as $e) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $e["kali"]; $i++)
        $res[] = array('um' => $e['um'], 'kali' => $cnt++);
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Dsn4la)

Comment: I believe it's a typo on OPs end, but your array has eight items, OPs has seven.

Comment: @Andreas - I also saw (noticed your comment) but guessed (as you) that the mistake is his

Comment: Yeah i mistake for that sample, should be 5 for um=2000, i'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this using `array_walk`

```
$arr = [
  ['um' => 1000, 'kali' => '2'],
  ['um' => 2000, 'kali' => '5'],
  ['um' => 5000, 'kali' => '1']
];
$res = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$res){
  $condition = ($v['kali'] == 5) ? 4 : ($v['kali']);
  for($i=1;$i <= $condition;$i++){
    $res[] = ['um' => $v['um'], 'kali' => count($res)+1]; 
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/v7Pq2)